# How to add regularization in CNN autoencoder model_Based on Keras

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder, regularized

I am a freshman in Keras and deep learning, I am not quite sure the right way to add the regularization, I wrote a CNN autoencoder using the API model class, right now I add the regularizer in each of the "Conv2D" Keras function,I am not sure if this is the right place to add regularization, could anyone please give me some suggestions?

(I tried to run the training and check the reconstructed test images, it is OK, but not very good, I use MNIST to test, the line of the reconstructed MNIST number is thicker than the original one.)

In my problem, the input image is an impaired one, and the original good image is used as a training label, by comparing the output image of the CNN with the training label image,  I use the "mean absolute error" to define the loss , and also use it as the metric.

I defined three functions first, one downsampling function (the one below), one upsampling function, and one function to squeeze the third dimension of the matrix to get a two-dimensional matrix as the output.
My code is too long, just to help illustrate the problem, part of my code is as follow:

[image: screenshot]

*After having three defined functions, I defined the model as follow (not in detail, just part of it to help explain my problem)*

[image: screenshot]

*load all necessary parameters to the model,then define the optimizer parameters, and compile the model*

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You are correct, conv2D is the right place for the regularization. You can also think about adding dropout.

Comment: Please add your code as text and mark it as code using the "code sample" tool" in the future.